# NSAssert works in debugger but the message is missing from console when run directly on device

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, llvm

NSAssert works fine in Xcode 4 (up to 4.6 inclusive) when running debugger. Assertion fires, you breakpoint it, then it outputs the assertion message.

But when running *outside* the debugger (debug build on device), assertions fire - but with no message.

This makes assertions useless: you can see the line number which asserted, but the detailed message from the programmer has been wiped.

Is this an Xcode problem? A clang/LLVM problem? Is it a setting with the wrong value? Or is there a workaround?

---

Example code:

```
NSAssert(FALSE, @"X was invalid: %i", x );
```

Example output (console):

```
<Warning>: *** Assertion failure in -[myClass method:], myClass.m:124
<Notice>: Formulating crash report for process MyApp[82]
```

Expected output (console):

```
<Warning>: *** Assertion failure in -[myClass method:], myClass.m:124
<Warning>: *** "X was invalid: -435"
<Notice>: Formulating crash report for process MyApp[82]
```

NB: I'm only guessing how Apple would format the assertion message.

---

**UPDATE:** Found the problem. I was wrong with my original description:

The message was *not* being output to console while running in the debugger

Answer (score 3):

Two observations:

1. The `NSAssert` is intended for debugging purposes only. When you build a release version of your app, `NSAssert` does nothing.
2. When you use `NSAssert` in a debug build of an app running on a device (not through the debugger), the message is in the device's console, not Xcode's. If you go to the "Organizer" in Xcode, choose "Devices", select your device and look at the "Console", you'll see your assertion there.

For example, I put in a line of code in a "Assertion Test" app:

```
NSAssert(FALSE, @"Assertion performed here");
```

When I look at the device's "Console" through Xcode's Organizer, I see:

```
Aug  6 09:10:53 Rob-iPod amfid[200] : Aug  6 09:10:53  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf CriticalExtensions IssuerCommonName]
Aug  6 09:10:53 Rob-iPod Assertion Test[199] : *** Assertion failure in -[ViewController viewDidLoad], /Users/rryan/Documents/Development/Xcode/Assertion Test/Assertion Test/ViewController.m:21
Aug  6 09:10:53 Rob-iPod kernel[0] : launchd[199] Builtin profile: container (sandbox)
Aug  6 09:10:53 Rob-iPod kernel[0] : launchd[199] Container: /private/var/mobile/Applications/7A7A62EF-8CEC-4388-932D-5C02DE77B841 (sandbox)
Aug  6 09:10:53 Rob-iPod Assertion Test[199] : *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Assertion performed here'
    *** First throw call stack:
    (0x315592a3 0x391d797f 0x3155915d 0x31e2eab7 0x843f7 0x33380595 0x333c0d79 0x333bcaed 0x333fe1e9 0x333c183f 0x333b984b 0x33361c39 0x333616cd 0x3336111b 0x350535a3 0x350531d3 0x3152e173 0x3152e117 0x3152cf99 0x3149febd 0x3149fd49 0x333b8485 0x333b5301 0x84149 0x3960eb20)
Aug  6 09:10:54 Rob-iPod ReportCrash[201] : Formulating crash report for process Assertion Test[199]
Aug  6 09:10:54 Rob-iPod com.apple.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:com.robertmryan.Assertion-Test[0x7be0][199]) : (UIKitApplication:com.robertmryan.Assertion-Test[0x7be0]) Job appears to have crashed: Abort trap: 6
Aug  6 09:10:54 Rob-iPod backboardd[26] : Application 'UIKitApplication:com.robertmryan.Assertion-Test[0x7be0]' exited abnormally with signal 6: Abort trap: 6
Aug  6 09:10:54 Rob-iPod ReportCrash[201] : libMobileGestalt copySystemVersionDictionaryValue: Could not lookup ReleaseType from system version dictionary
Aug  6 09:10:54 Rob-iPod ReportCrash[201] : Saved crashreport to /var/mobile/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/Assertion Test_2013-08-06-091053_Rob-iPod.plist using uid: 0 gid: 0, synthetic_euid: 501 egid: 0
```

If you look at that fifth line, you'll see the assertion message there.

Comment: 1. As stated in original question, the assertion is firing. Obviously, if I'd disabled assertions, I'd expect nothing to happen. 2. Your "fifth line" never appears for me when run outside Xcode, but does appear when run inside xcode

Comment: More specifically: your 2nd and 6th lines appear for me, but your 5th line does not.

Comment: How do you look at the console in the main Xcode window *without* running the debugger? I thought that was impossible

Comment: @Adam As I said, go to the Xcode "Organizer" (choose "Organizer" from Xcode's "Window" menu), then click on "Devices" ...

Comment: OK, makes no difference. What's magical about Xcode organizer? What's it reading that isn't the iOS console?

Comment: Thanks for the help - looks like it was my own stupid fault for mis-describing the problem :(

Answer (score 0):

This is very situation specific ... I hadn't realised, but we had HockeyApp / QuincyKit embedded in the app.

Hockey appears to have a nasty bug where it:

1. captures NSAssertions
2. Allows them to crash
3. Deletes the message
4. Deletes the logging
5. ... does *not* upload anything to the Hockey website

So ... the messages were visible in the debugger, but only in the debugger variables - I was a fool, and not paying attention: they weren't appearing in the console.

---

To be clear: some assertions sometimes appear in Hockey (looking at the Hockey console), but most assertions are silently missing. 100% of App crashes appear, but only about 10% of assertion crashes.

Comment: Very good. While it was undoubtedly frustrating, I can understand the logic in Hockey not bothering to deal with this. There's no point and them handling `NSAssert` in a framework designed for reporting production crashes, because production code which is a release build should never have assertions, anyway (`NSAssert` is a null op in release build). But it's good to have the mystery solved!

Comment: Yep, but ... with a large number of devices to test on a debug build (20+ physical devices ... it's a complex product) ... Hockey has the potential to make development much faster (auto updating builds, auto-reporting to a centralised DB, etc). I'm sure we're not the only ones to try using Hockey on debug builds :)

Comment: Hopefully the Hockey [discussion forums](http://support.hockeyapp.net/discussions) or [support page](http://support.hockeyapp.net) can help. Good luck.